# NSDate extension for specific day of each week

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm looking to extend the NSDate class so I am able to reference the Tuesday of each week we're currently in as an NSDate.

I understand that this can be done with NSDateComponents. So far I have the below:

```
extension NSDate {

var tuesday: NSDate {

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let todaysDate = NSDate()

    let weekdayComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday | .CalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal, fromDate: todaysDate)

    weekdayComponents.weekday = 3

    let returnTuesday = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(weekdayComponents, toDate: todaysDate, options: nil)

    return returnTuesday!
}}
```

I believe that the CalendarUnitWeekday work on an index based system (i.e. Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7), which is why I am setting the required weekday to 3 for Tuesday.

However when initialising an NSDate object and accessing this extended 'tuesday' property, I am receiving a date a month in advance.

(todays date - "Aug 26, 2015, 4:42 PM")
(tuesday date - "Sep 26, 2015, 4:42 PM")

What is causing this advancement of a month? Is there a way to return a specific date of each week we are in through extending the NSDate class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `dateByAddingComponents:` you can find today's weekday and get its difference with the target weekday and update the day component.
The required date can be generated by `dateFomComponents` method using the updated components parameter.

```
extension NSDate {

    var tuesday: NSDate {

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: NSDate())
        let targetDay = 3 //Required day
        let today = components.weekday

        if (targetDay < today) {
            components.day -= today - targetDay
        } else {
            components.day += targetDay - today
        }

        return calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
    }}
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for! Thanks for the clear breakdown also.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `dateByAddingComponents` which is going to take the date provided and add a number of time units to it based on the date components. Those date components have been requested as `CalendarUnitWeekday` and `CalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal`. You have explicitly set one of these to 3 and the other is set to whatever the current date is. So, when you add them, you aren't setting the weekday to 3, you're adding 3 to the week day (probably, I'm not even sure adding a week day to a date makes sense so it might not do this - it may be logical why you move by a month, it may not...) and another value to the week day ordinal. This obviously isn't what you want.

Instead, you should be finding out the current week day and adding / subtracting days until you get to the first next or previous Tuesday. Then, once you're there, you can sanely add days / weeks to this date to get any other required dates.